# LinearLayout display item bottom to up

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

i have a LinearLayout. and i am adding item in runtime. but all the items are display from TOP to BOTTOM. Now i am trying to display items BOTTOM to TOP.

I mean. i want to starting from BOTTOM to TOP for set the items in linear layout.

This is my linear layout:-

```
 messagesContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.messagesContainer);
    scrollContainer = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollContainer);

   LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


    if (!leftSide) {
        bgRes = R.drawable.right_message_bg;
        params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
        params.leftMargin=30;
    }
    else
    {
        params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
        params.rightMargin=30;
    }

    textView.setLayoutParams(params);

    textView.setBackgroundResource(bgRes);

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            messagesContainer.addView(textView,messagesContainer.getChildCount());

            //messagesContainer.bringChildToFront(textView);

            // Scroll to bottom
            if (scrollContainer.getChildAt(0) != null) {
                scrollContainer.scrollTo(scrollContainer.getScrollX(), scrollContainer.getChildAt(0).getHeight());
            }
            scrollContainer.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
            scrollContainer.pageScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
        }
    });
```

please help me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add it programmatically with:

```
LinearLayout layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
layout.addView(newView, index);
```

You just have to add always with index = 0

And you can also use `android:gravity="bottom"`

Comment: i m sry not working. it is just message display in viewgroup. but msg is displaying from top to bottom. and i want to display it bottom to top

Comment: i want to give bottom text to index = 0

Comment: Did you give layout.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

Comment: but my bottom text index is total msg.

Comment: If you confuse with Linear then use Relative

Comment: Use layoutParams.addRule(LinearLayout.BOTTOM, 1);

Answer (score 1):

## Gravity.

> Also, If you want the message to display from bottom to top, you need to add
> them to the `ViewGroup` in that order.

Set the Gravity to **BOTTOM**

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
            params.weight = 1.0f;
            params.gravity=48;

            button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

For gravity values and how to set gravity check [Gravity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html#TOP)